# Newly created columns for from contenttypehub not reflecting in other site collections

Tags: 2013, office-365, 2016

I created a Content Type in `contenttypehub` in office 365

I added a new column to it

But when I refresh the contenttype, its not appearing in site content types

Is there something like a timer job which I should run for my changes to appear in the contenttype?

Answer (score 2):

It usually take 60-90 mins to get the new column in the destination site.

However, you can go to

`https://dest-sitecolletion-url/_layouts/15/contenttypesyndicationhubs.aspx`

and on that page, click on the **Refresh checkbox** and click OK.

[image]

You will find it under the Management section as below:

[image]

Check reference image below:

Reference - [Content type publishing in Office 365](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/21859.aspx)

[image]

Comment: i did this, but columns are still not appearing in other site collections

Comment: You need to wait at least 60-90 mins. The columns will appear afterwards only. If you think you have waited long enough then check the logs for errors.

Comment: no errors, but still columns are not appearing !

Comment: Ok, question 1) did you publish your content types ? 2) In Office 365, there is https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contenttypehub , is your content type present there ?

Comment: Yeah I created it the content types in the contenttypehub and published them 
content type is present, but the columns that I added to it are not there

Comment: the columns are visible in the contenttypehub, but they are still not published to other site collections

Comment: if you have published it , then there will be published history. So after you have added a new column, you need to republish it and wait for 60-90 mins and also check the checkbox again in the dest site. Check this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwT5h.png